# How to login users with the built-in admin login panel for my own app?

Tags: django, authentication

`Django` comes with a built-in admin page, which has it's own login panel.

Most Django sites implement their own login panel. That makes sense, since it gives them a lot of flexibility. But for some apps it would be sufficient to use the existing admin login panel instead of implementing your own.

Of course I could just redirect the user to the admin login page. However, after login the user is automatically is redirected to the main admin page and I would like him to be redirected to my app'
s page instead.

How can I use Django's built-in admin login panel for my own app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to seamlessly integrate the admin login panel into your app, by redirecting to your app's page instead of the admin site.

The Django admin site provides default views for login and logout as documented [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#reversing-admin-urls):

- `admin:login`
- `admin:logout`

Both views support the `next` URL parameter, which allows you to specify to which page the user will be redirected after completing the process step. This allows you to specify your own app's pages instead of the admin site.

Note that there is one caveat to this approach: The admin login panel will only work for users, which have the staff role.

#### Example template snippet

For this Django template we are assuming your app is called `my_app` and this template is part of an view called `my_app:index`.

```
{% if request.user.is_authenticated == False %}
    <p>
        You are currently not logged in. Click 
        <a href="{% url 'admin:login' %}?next={% url 'my_app:index' %}">here</a>
         to login.
    </p>

{% else%}
    <p>
        You are logged in as user: <b>{{ request.user.username }}</b> 
        <a href="{% url 'admin:logout' %}?next={% url 'my_app:index' %}">[Logout]
        </a>
    </p>    

{% endif %}
```